# Выборка MySQL. Соединение, группировка, подсчет

Tags: php, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть таблица Z и таблица P.
Как соединить две таблицы и объединить статусы и подсчитать их количество чтобы получилась выборка результат который показан на картинке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT z.idz, z.name,
       COALESCE(SUM(p.statusp=0),0) `0`,
       COALESCE(SUM(p.statusp=1),0) `1`,
       COALESCE(SUM(p.statusp=2),0) `2`,
       COALESCE(SUM(p.statusp=3),0) `3`
FROM z
LEFT JOIN p ON z.idz=p.idz
GROUP BY z.idz  ;
```